# What does the google.maps.Projection class do?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-projections

Recently I found out the hard way that to convert between LatLngs and pixel coordinates on screen I shouldn't use the [Projection](http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Projection) class that is easily accessed through Map.getProjection, but instead I should use the [MapCanvasProjection](http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapCanvasProjection) class that can only be accessed through OverlayView.

The latter is nice and handy if you are working with a custom overlay, but if you're not, it's really painful to get access to the MapCanvasProjection. So far I have solved this problem for myself by adding a method to the Map class that will give me easy access to the desired projection class:

```js
google.maps.Map.prototype.getCanvasProjection = function() {
  if (!this.projectionOverlay) {
    this.projectionOverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    this.projectionOverlay.onAdd = function(){};
    this.projectionOverlay.onRemove = function(){};
    this.projectionOverlay.draw = function(){};
    this.projectionOverlay.setMap(this);
  }
  return this.projectionOverlay.getProjection();
};
```

This all looks like a big hack to do something that should be trivial. And it ever more makes me wonder what does the [google.maps.Projection](http://code.google.com/intl/et-EE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Projection) class do? When I read the documentation it seems to me that `Projection.fromLatLngToPoint` does the same thing as `MapCanvasProjection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel`, but it does not. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projection.fromLatLngToPoint means converting from Latitude Longitude to Mercator projection. MapCanvasProjection does a projection to pixel (including Mercator).

Comment: OK, I think I mostly get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, here you have it :) When I tried to do it yesterday, Stackoverflow sayd I can't do that.